# Undefined reference while calling GUROBI in C, Codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, undefined-reference, gurobi

I downloaded Codeblocks to call GUROBI - an optimization package with libraries- from C. While building the example C code from GUROBI ([See  here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/mip1_c_c.html)), I get 15 errors in the form of:

```
.../main.c:32: undefined reference to `GRBloadenv@8'
.../main.c:32: undefined reference to `GRBreadmodel@12'
```

I already did the following:

1. In global compiler settings

   - Set *Settings>Compiler>Search Directories>Compiler* path to GUROBI's include folder (with .h files)
   - Set *Search Directories>Linker* path to GUROBI's lib folder (with .lib files)
   - Link libraries from Linker settings.
2. Did the same three steps above for the prject itself, i.e. *Project>Build Options>...[same as Step 1]*

Having spent the whole day, i cant find any solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

I'm working on Windows 10, Code::Blocks 17.12, and Gurobi 8.1.0

[image: Global compiler path to .h files]
[image]
[image]